# Python interface to Titan Database

Tags: python, databases, nosql

How can I connect to Titan database from Python ?

What I understand is that Titan (Graph database) provides an interface (Blueprint) to Cassandra (Column Store) and 
bulb is a python interface to graph DB.

Now how can I start programming in python to connect with titan DB?
Is there any good documentation/tutorial available ?

Comment: [Bulbflow- A python interface to graph databases](http://bulbflow.com/overview/); [Bulb Docs](http://bulbflow.com/docs/); [A snarky answer](http://bit.ly/1zvehXv). Note this question has been solved already on [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24990607/bulbs-python-connection-to-a-remote-titandb-rexster), which is where it belongs because it specifically relates to programming.

Comment: The first Google result on the [snarky answer](http://bit.ly/1zvehXv) now leads back to this page :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Rexster](https://github.com/tinkerpop/rexster/wiki/Basic-REST-API) to expose a REST api and then you can use this api via [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module (there are many other modules to do this task - though Requests is what I prefer)

Answer (score 1):

I have had success using [Mogwai Python Library](https://bitbucket.org/wellaware/mogwai)  which is more actively maintained than Bulbs at this point.

Though I agree that this belongs on stack overflow.